# Typeof() operator in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, typeof

Im writing some helper functions for a project im working on. I've always wanted a typeof operator. I know it doesn't exist in my current IDE (visual studio '10), so im trying to write an implementation for it. It should work something like this:

```
auto var = new typeof(<expression>);
```

It should just be a compile-time retrievable type based off the expression and should be possible. C++ uses this when inducing template arguments, for instance:

```
template< typename A >
void foo(A unused) { 
/*  can be invoked like foo(5) with A = int     */
    typedef A type;
    type * used = new type;
}
```

So i thought i could play around with macroes, classes and templates.. something like this:

```
#define typeof(expression)  (_type_creater().inducer(expression)::type)

template<typename T>
class _type_holder{
public:
    typedef T type;
};

class _type_creater{
public:
template< class B >
    _type_holder<B> inducer(B _temp) {
        /*  Here compiler induces the templated expression and creates a typename out of it.
            this we can use extract typename from _type_holder, except a instantiatet type apparantly
            doesn't have access to typedef'd typenames.
        */
        return _type_holder<B>();
    }
};
```

So the problem is basically, that this is illegal:

```
struct a
{
   typedef int type;
}
...
a mya;
new mya::type; //or mya.type
```

So the first question is, why is this illegal? Why can't you retrieve typenames from instantiatet types?
Second question, can i do this at all? I tried looking a boosts TYPEOF, but couldn't make much sense of it, and it seems it just utilizes bugs in VC compilers ("//VC7.0 specific bugfeature", "//VC8.0 specific bugfeature", "// This uses nice VC6.5 and VC7.1 bugfeature"). 
Am i out of luck?

Comment: "*I've always wanted a typeof operator. I know it doesn't exist in my current IDE (visual studio '10)*" Yes it does -- it's called [`decltype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537655.aspx).

Comment: @ildjarn i love you thanks. dont know how i overlooked it. As for the first question, though... ?

Comment: I don't know what answer you're looking for. The syntax is illegal -- you want to know _why_ it's illegal? I don't think anyone who isn't on the ISO C++ committee can reasonably answer that question.

Comment: Given the previous example, it is legal to do a::type, but not mya::type. Yes i guess i wonder why, perhaps there's a logical reason behind this?

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt anyone that knows that reason posts here.

Comment: Types only exist at compile time. Everything that only exists at compile time is accessed with `::` (scope resolution, as scopes only exist at compile time). Everything that exists at runtime can be accessed with `.` (member access). Actually, classes don't exist at runtime too, they're just some byte blobs that have certain funtions associated with them and whose members are just at certain offsets. That's my interpretation, anyways.

Comment: Note that `decltype` has some issues in VS 2010.  Namely, it apparently uses an older version of the `decltype` proposal, and doesn't support using `decltype` on non-static class members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object is not a scope. The scope resolution operator (`::`) is only applicable to scopes (class scope, namespace scope, global (namespace) scope). I gave a bit of additional information as a theory in a comment on the question.